# \b while text wrapping wont go back

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that sends `\b`, sends a space, then another `\b`.

Currently, it deletes the last character fine, but not after the text wraps to a new line, shown here:
[image: Example of what happens]

This isn't what I want, I would like it to delete the characters on the first line, and not just stop at the start of the new one.
Here's my code currently:

```
import sys
import msvcrt
def getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None):
    """Prompt for password with echo off, using Windows getch()."""
    for c in prompt:
        msvcrt.putwch(c)
    pw = ""
    typed = 0
    while True:
        c = msvcrt.getwch()
        if c == '\r' or c == '\n':
            break
        if c == '\003':
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        if c == '\b':
            pw = pw[:-1]
            if not len(pw) == 0:
                typed = 1
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
                msvcrt.putwch("\u0020")
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
            elif typed == 1:
                typed = 0
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
                msvcrt.putwch("\u0020")
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
        else:
            pw = pw + c
            msvcrt.putwch("*")
            typed = 1
    msvcrt.putwch('\r')
    msvcrt.putwch('\n')
    return pw
```

And the problem is here:

```
        if c == '\b':
            pw = pw[:-1]
            if not len(pw) == 0:
                typed = 1
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
                msvcrt.putwch("\u0020")
                msvcrt.putwch("\b")
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Looks like it is a feature of the terminal emulator (I see the same behavior in X terminal on Linux). By the way, `"\u0020"` is simply `" "`, there is no need to obscure the fact that you print a blank space.

Comment: This could be done using the Windows console API or curses.

Comment: @DYZ I didn't think you could put normal spaces in `msvcrt.putwch()`.